# jQuery hover effect issue on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery-hover

I basically wrote my own jQuery hover effect plugin that works in all browsers except in IE(9,8,7)....

Here is the link : http://www.fiver.org/web/testing
This is the code:

```js
function go()
{

  hoverEffect = document.getElementsByName("hoverEffect");
  for (i=0; i<hoverEffect.length; i++)
  {
    $(hoverEffect[i]).bind('mouseenter', bMouseOver);
    $(hoverEffect[i]).bind('mouseleave', bMouseOut);
  }

  function bMouseOver(e)
  { 
    $(this).find(".fadebox")
      .animate({opacity: 1},
      300);                                         
  }


  function bMouseOut(e)
  { 
    $(this).find(".fadebox")
      .animate({opacity: 0},
      {duration: 'slow'});

  }


}

$(document).ready(function(){
    go();
});
```

it's a basic hover effect that's cracking my head! do you have any ideas???

Best,

Comment: You kinda gave us half code and a broken link

Comment: @Chris formatting issue, I just fixed that part at least.

Answer (score 0):

IE-s getElementsByName has some problems, i wouldn't rely on it.

Try to give those elements a class, instead of name, and select them with jQuery.

Example

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverEffect">one</div>    
<div class="hoverEffect">two</div>
<div class="hoverEffect">three</div>
```

Selecting them with JQuery, and assigning events:

```
$(".hoverEffect").bind('mouseenter', bMouseOver);
$(".hoverEffect").bind('mouseleave', bMouseOut);
```

This will also get rid of an extra iterating through the DOM and the using of needless arrays (hoverEffect[])

Comment: Since the elements have name attributes, why not just use jQuery to select the name? `$('[name="hoverEffect"]')`. Not the fastest selector, but it shouldn't be slower than using a class selector.

Comment: Your class selector also has an issue you forgot your "."

Comment: @Michal that's just my coding style, whatever you wish

Answer (score -1):

Try using opacity:.00 instead of opacity:0

jQuery opacity animations work better when using .00 as zero opacity instead of 0. I can't really explain and find any documentation why this is, but it had fixed my problems in the past.

Also a little more information about what doesn't work in this script would help :)